# Can't connect to network share from "Go>Network"

Tags: network, macos, file-sharing

When I try to connect to a shared volume on another Mac on my LAN, I get "Connection Failed."

If I try to connect with "Go > Connect to Server..." and use IP address, it works fine.

But if I try to mount through Finder window "Go > Network" I get "Connection Failed."

Both machines are on El Capitan, both are logged in to the same icloud account, both have the same user/password.

I can see the icon for the other machine, but when I double click I get "Connection Failed."

Clicking "Connect As..." just changes this to "Not connected."

Comment: Using the Finder (or sidebar in the Finder) uses Bonjour to discover servers. In the Connect To Server dialog you're entering an IP Address or host name. So my hunch is there's something going on with Bonjour discovery...

When the connection fails is there something relevant in the system.log file on either system?

Comment: @MacManager What would I look for in the log? I'm not seeing anything that looks relevant.

Comment: Hmm, I changed the Computer Name and now it seems to be working again.

Comment: However after changing the name back, and trying to open a shared folder, I get *"The operation can’t be completed because the original item for ___ can’t be found."* Is there a way to delete/reset the client machine's cache/history of connected servers? Clearly something is being cached/saved.

Comment: Strange... did you change the name of the machine you're connecting from (client) or connecting to (server)? Just curious.. Perhaps try Safe Boot (hold `Shift` while starting up) and then reboot again normally?